# how to fetch required content only using strip_tags function in php

Tags: php, strip-tags

I'am using strip_tags function to fetch only required content but it fetches the whole data from a link
see the example code below i m using to fetch content from a link:

```
<?php

$a=fopen("http://example.com/","r");
$contents=stream_get_contents($a);
fclose($a);
$contents1=strtolower($contents);

$start='<div id="content">';

$start_pos=strpos($contents1,$start);
$first_trim=substr($contents1,$start_pos);

$stop='</div><!-- content -->';
$stop_pos=strpos($first_trim,$stop);

$second_trim=substr($first_trim,0,$stop_pos+6);
$second_trim = strip_tags($second_trim, '<div><table><tbody><tr><td><a><h2><h4>');
echo "<div>$second_trim</div>";
?>
```

here is the html code fetched in $second_trim:

```
<div><div id="content">
<div id="issuedescription"></div>
    <h2 class="wsite-content-title" style="text-align:center;">download content<br /><font     color="#f30519">table of content</font><br />&nbsp;<font color="#f80117"> content&nbsp;</font></h2>

    <h2>table of contents</h2>   
<h4 class="tocsectiontitle">editorial</h4>
<h2 class="wsite-content-title" style="text-align:left;">technical note</h2>        
<table class="tocarticle" width="100%">
<tr valign="top">           
<td class="toctitle" width="95%" align="left"><a     href="http://example.com/">where are we at and where are we heading to?</a>            </td>
    <td class="tocgalleys" width="5%" align="left">
                                <a href="http://example.com/"     class="file">pdf</a>                                          
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tocauthors" width="95%" align="left">
                                sergio eduardo de paiva gonã§alves                      </td>
    <td class="tocpages" width="5%" align="left">1-2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="separator"></div>
h4 class="tocsectiontitle">some text here</h4>

<table class="tocarticle" width="100%">
<tr valign="top">

    <td class="toctitle" width="95%" align="left"><a     href="http://example.com/">some text here</a></td>
    <td class="tocgalleys" width="5%" align="left">
                                <a href="http://example.com/"     class="file">pdf</a>

            </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td class="tocauthors" width="95%" align="left">
                                some text here,                         some text here,                         some text here,                         some text here,                         some text here,                         some text here                      </td>
    <td class="tocpages" width="5%" align="left">3-10</td>
</tr>
</table>
    <a target="_blank" rel="license" href="http://example.com/">    
    </a>
    some text here<a rel="license" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/">example</a>.
    </div></div>
```

Now my problem is i want to fetch a particular tag only, from the whole content like 2nd anchor from two of given below using strip_tag function

```
<a href="http://example.com/" class="file">pdf</a>
<a href="http://example.com/">some text here</a>
```

and 2nd header tag from two of given below:

```
<h2 class="wsite-content-title" style="text-align:center;">download content<br /><font color="#f30519">table of content</font><br />&nbsp;<font color="#f80117"> content&nbsp;</font></h2>

<h2>table of contents</h2>
```

but strip tag function is either fetching all of them or none of them , So how can i make them identify to fetch the tag I want instead of fetching all the similar tags.If their is any better way to do this please share your ideas here !!

Comment: `strip_tags` is far too clumsy. Use `DomDocument` - reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: thnx for replying Mike but i've to implement it in xml format i dont know xml and DOM is also new for me i am just a begginer in php can you give me a little example to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regexp can do such a thing:

```
function handle_link($data) {
    list($link, $attributes, $content) = $data;
    $classes = preg_match('#class=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]#', $attributes, $match) ? preg_split('#\s+#', $match[1]) : array();
    // If the link has the "file" class
    if(in_array('file', $classes)) {
        return $content; // only the internal content (like strip_tags would do)
        // or you can return a new link:
        // return '<a href="myfile" class="myclass">' . $content . '</a>';
    } else {
        return $link; // all the link not filtered
    }
}

$second_trim = strip_tags($second_trim, '<div><table><tbody><tr><td><h2><h4>');
$second_trim = preg_replace_callback('#<a([^>]*)>(.+)</a>#U', 'handle_link', $second_trim);
```

Comment: thanx for replying mr. KyleK i run your code but its giving the syntax error :: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on 3rd line of your code at &classes variable . but i think this is the right concept for my question can you test it again to get more accurate code .

Comment: The quotes in quotes wasn't escaped. And i added `$second_trim =` missing at the end.

Comment: awesome man its working now !! :D you gave me right concept and that's exacly what i was looking for ...thanx alot ;)

Comment: HEYY their is one more thing , you removed the link their at pdf but can you remove that text too? i.e. removing the text written in td tag "pdf" ::<td class="tocgalleys" width="5%" align="left">
                                <a href="http://example.com/"     class="file">pdf</a>                                          
</td>

Comment: Try to understand the code: for each `<a...>...</a>`, handle_link is called with `$data` containing the parenthesis of the RegExp. Then it's replaced by the value returned by the function. So you can test and return whatever you wish in the function. You can `return $link;` (no change) `return $content;` (only the text) `return "";` (remove all the text and tag) `return "Hello Wolrd!"` (replace by your own text or HTML code, as in the example in the comments).
PS: do not forget to validate the answer.

Comment: dont worry you deserve more than this .. but actually i m just a beginner in php so this regex is new for me but i've started learning it .so for now it would be of a big help if you can help me little more

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do the job. See the function, you have a return $content if file class is present, and return $link else. So I think here you know wich return you have to modify. And if you want replace the link with nothing, just return nothing (ie. an empty string: "").

Comment: its' done , thnx man i really appreciate your skills , you're doing great job big applause for you :D ;)

Comment: HI,@mr. KyleK thnx for the previous help but i m getting more problem on this and again i need your help what if  have two select one tag from two equal tags but having different texts i.e. <p>some text</p> <p>some other text</p> now i want to remove only one "p" tag what will you suggest as only text is different but the tags are same

Comment: one more thing i want to ask if we want  to remove more than one tag and change the font of the remaining text , all this in one function , is it possible thanx in advance

Comment: Now, you should start to get a bit of autonomy. See the doc: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php maybe the limit parameter is what you need.